# Is it possible to run ls or find and pipe it through stat?

Tags: bash, find, ls, stat

Is there a way to run ls or find to get the list of files within a directory and then run stat to get all of the specific information (i.e. File Group, File Name, File Owner, File Size (displayed in K, M, etc.) & Permissions? I was trying something along the lines of:

```
find .content/media -type f | stat
ls -l .content/media | stat
```

Answer:

```
    find ./content/"subdirectory name"/ -type f -exec stat -c '%n : %U : %A : %G : %s' {} +
```

Comment: `find` will recursively list all the subdirectories within its argument. `ls` will not; for the equivalent of the `ls` pipe, just do `stat ./content/media/*`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `stat` on the `-exec` action of `find`:

```
find .content/media/ -type f -exec stat -c '%n : %U : %G : %s' {} +
```

Change the format sequences of `stat` to meet your need.

Comment: Could you explain what the -exec command does? I understand that it runs a section of "program". In this instance is it running executing -stat as a program after running -find?

Comment: @lettda `-exec` is an action of `find`..you can use it to run some other program over the result of `find` ..check `man find`

Answer (score 12):

If you have GNU find, you can use `-printf`:

```
find content/media/ -type f -printf '%p : %u : %g : %k'
```

Answer (score 8):

Throw `xargs` into the mix. E.g.:

```
ls | xargs stat
```

Comment: This will fail with spaces or newlines in the filenames.

Comment: To handle newlines or spaces you would use: `find -print0 | xargs -0 stat`.

Comment: If one is using ls that's a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with a simple Bash `for`-loop?

```
for f in ./*
do
    stat "$f"
done
```

With the quotes and the `./` prefix, this is safe against the worst file names.

Comment: Or just `stat *`

Comment: Oh, if `stat` supports that, even better. I would still go with `./*` as a file starting with `-h` would cause undesired behavior otherwise.

Comment: Use `stat -- *` then.

Comment: Yes, but the program needs to support the double dash, not all do. Therefore the dot-slash is more universal.

Answer (score 1):

```
find .content/media -type f -exec stat -c '%n : %U : %G : %s : %x : %y : %z' {} +

%n     File name,
%U     User name of owner,
%G     Group name of owner,
%s     Total size, in bytes,
%x     Time of last access,
%y     Time of last modification,
%z     Time of last change.
```